# Is it possible to set an element's margin-top as 60% of another element's height with SCSS?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, ionic2

Question says it all.
Is it possible to set an element's margin-top as 60% of another element's height with SCSS?

I'm developing an Ionic 2 app, targeting browsers, Android, iOS and Windows Phone. Here are the elements:

```
  <div class='logoBox'>
    <img src="assets/img/-.png" class="corner-logo" alt="-" />
    <img src="assets/img/icon.png" class="logo" id="logo" alt="-" />
  </div>
  <div class='headerBox' id="headerBox">...</div>
```

This is how I'm setting positioning right now:

```
  ionViewDidEnter(){
    document.getElementById('headerBox').style.marginTop = Math.round(Number(document.getElementById('logo')['height']) * 0.6) + 'px';
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', () => {
      document.getElementById('headerBox').style.marginTop = Math.round(Number(document.getElementById('logo')['height']) * 0.6) + 'px';
    });
  }
```

My current method works in the browser, but when running on a real device as an app, the 'orientationchange' **event listener is fired only sometimes**, as evident in visual results.

So is it possible to achieve the same with SCSS, so that it works everywhere?
If not, can I achieve it with JS?

Comment: have u tried to put those element height into the variable ? and then just converting those elements margins you need with `$thoseVariableHeight*60/ 100 `?

Comment: I'm an SCSS noob so no idea about that. Will have to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is an answer but anyway

SCSS

```
$marginVar = 200px // for example 
.element-with-height{
 margin-top: $marginVar ;
}
// if those elements that you want to affect is not nested inside `.element-with-height`
.affected-elements{
 height: $marginVar * 60 / 100   // so you get 60% as from the question
}
```

So in fact you are just using `variables` as "sugar" from scss

Answer (score 0):

You need to bear in mind that scss outputs to valid CSS. It doesn't add anything new to the frontend, it just (hopefully) streamlines the backend (for example by adding features that mean you to not have to do calculations and value transformations yourself).

So the question really becomes 'can you do this in CSS'.

As ddeadlink points out, if the height of the logo element is fixed (or you can tweak the design to make it fixed), then you could set the height as a variable and use scss to calculate 60% of it. If not, then you're stuck with updating using JS.